# How to interpret Terrain Ruggedness Index according to Wilson et al. (2007)?

Tags: raster, r, dem, terrain

Is there a categorical scale used to interpret values from the Terrain Ruggedness Index as calculated by Wilson et al. (2007), which is used in the `raster` [library](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/terrain.html) in R?

Comment: It helps if you can link to cited research, saves us tracking down the articles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper by [Riley et al (1999)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259011943_A_Terrain_Ruggedness_Index_that_Quantifies_Topographic_Heterogeneity) cited by the [Wilson et al](https://www2.unil.ch/biomapper/Download/Wilson-MarGeo-2007.pdf) paper has a map with seven categories of ruggedness (and an odd colour scheme but whatever)...

[image]

They use an "equal area" basis for the breakpoints, which I guess means they were chose so that each category is the same area on the map, which seems a bit arbitrary but unless you have some idea of what "rugged" means then I guess its as good as any other...

Comment: I'm looking at these values for southern Arizona. So if I divide the range of values in my map into 10 categories, then that would give me a relative categorical scale I could use to assign to values I sample from points in the area?

Comment: That's what they do in the paper, but with 7 categories, with the breaks in the categories set so that exactly 1/7 of the area is in the "Level" category, 1/7 in "Nearly Level" and so on. For any vector of values `z` you can get the breakpoints for 7 categories with `quantile(z,seq(0,1,len=8))` - but the category definitions will be different for Arizona if you work them out for Nebraska.